# Postfix Notation calculation program in C, having some problems

Tags: c, postfix-notation

I'm attempting to create a program to run calculations in postfix notation using C, and reading in values from the unix command line. I, however, am quite new to the C language, and am having a bit of trouble getting things to work correctly. I'm getting readouts of NULL and Segmentation Faults, but I'm not really sure how debugging works in the unix command line, so I can't tell you where I am getting the error. I would appreciate any help on the matter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
double stack(int argc, char* argv[]);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {


    double result;

    result = stack(argc, argv);


    printf("%s\n", result);


}
```

--

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
static double stck[100];
static int top = 0;

/*Push Function*/
static void push( double v){

    stck[top] = v; /* Places the value at the current top position of the stack */
    top++; /* Increases the top position of the stack */
    printf("%s\n", top);

}
/*Pop Function*/
static double pop() {

    double ret;
    ret = stck[top]; /* Stores the value of the top position in the stack to ret */
    top--; /* Decreases the top position of the stack */
    printf("%s\n", top);
    return ret; /* Returns the value of ret */

}

double stack(int argc, char* argv[]){

    double h; /* Placeholder Variable for the result of the mathematic equations during the loop */
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= argc - 1; i++) { /* Loops to read in all values, barring the first, for argv */

        if (strcmp(argv[i], "*") == 0) {

            double a = pop();  /* Pulls in the top value of the stack */
            double b = pop();  /* Pulls in the next top value of the stack*/
            h = b*a; /* Performs the multiplication of the two stack values */
            push(h); /* Returns the result to the top of the stack */

        } else if (strcmp(argv[i], "+") == 0) {
            printf("%s\n", "Made it here plus \0");
            double a = pop();  /* Pulls in the top value of the stack */
            double b = pop();  /* Pulls in the next top value of the stack*/
            h = b+a;  /* Performs the multiplication of the two stack values */
            push(h);  /* Returns the result to the top of the stack */

        } else if (strcmp(argv[i], "/") == 0) {

            double a = pop();  /* Pulls in the top value of the stack */
            double b = pop();  /* Pulls in the next top value of the stack*/
            h = b/a; /* Performs the division of the two stack values */
            push(h);  /* Returns the result to the top of the stack */


        } else if (strcmp(argv[i], "^") == 0) {

            double a = pop();  /* Pulls in the top value of the stack */
            double b = pop();  /* Pulls in the next top value of the stack*/
            h = pow(b,a);  /* Raises the number b by the number a power */
            push(h);  /* Returns the result to the top of the stack */


        } else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-") == 0) {

            double a = pop();  /* Pulls in the top value of the stack */
            double b = pop();  /* Pulls in the next top value of the stack*/
            h = b-a;  /* Performs the subtraction of the two stack values */
            push(h);  /* Returns the result to the top of the stack */

        } else {
            printf("%s\n", "Made it here \0");

            double ph;

            ph = (double)atof(argv[i]);
            printf("%s\n", ph);

            push(ph); /* Places the current value of argv[i] on the top of the stack */

        }

    }
    return stck[0]; /* Returns the final result of the calculation to main.c */


}
```

Comment: `top` is defined as an integer, you should print it using the integer format specifier for `printf`; `printf("%d\n", top);`

Comment: Also printf("%s\n", result); Should be printf("%lf\n", result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your push and pop operations need to be the exact reverse of each other.

So if push is

```
stackarray[index] = v
index++     //increment last
```

pop must be

```
index--     //decrement first
return stackarray[index]
```

otherwise, pop will always return the value from one slot *after* the most recently pushed value.

---

Debugging a program that uses command-line arguments shouldn't be much different from debugging any other program. But you may need to read the debugger's documentation to learn how to pass the arguments to the program. In gdb:

```
gdb> break main
gdb> run arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

That is, add the arguments to the `run` line, as if `run` were the name of the program.

Comment: Hey, thanks man, you are a life saver. Fixed it, and everything is working as intended. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. If this answer really does solve it, you should click the checkmark to *accept* the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`printf()` format specifier `%s` requires an argument of `character array`.but here `top` is `integer` so you need to use `%d` format specifier.

Change all

```
 printf("%s\n", top);  ==> printf("%d\n", top);
          ^                         ^
```

Comment: Thank you for that, It's really helped. I can see all my values now and see that now the only problem I'm having is the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Check all your printf's to make sure the format specifier matches the argument.

Comment: Thank you for that, I had no idea C had a different specifier for each type.

Comment: [Then I offer you this link too all the gory details.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)